# Automatically merge pdf presentations pages

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

I would like to print a pdf presentation, however each paragraph of the presentation is shown on a next page of the pdf presentation, so for a 3 paragraphs per slide, 1<sup>st</sup> page contains paragraph 1, 2<sup>nd</sup> page contains paragraphs 1 and 2 and the 3<sup>rd</sup> one contains paragraphs 1, 2, 3. Note that each slide contains variable number of these transitions.
Although the Adobe Acrobat correctly shows that there are only 17 slides, if I print it, it prints all the 40 pages including the duplicates described above. I would like to save the pdf such as there are only those 17 pages without doing it manually (or at least print them).

I would be really grateful for help or link for help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to view the PDF as "build" slides, where you see all 40 pages, but print only the 17 "complete" slides as hard copy.  I'm not aware of a way to store the PDF in a manner that automatically displays one way and prints a different way.  So you couldn't simply distribute the PDF and any recipient could just click Print and get the shortened output.  A few options:

- At print time, you would need to specify the print pages.  You can do that as a single print job by specifying a comma separated list of pages and page ranges (like: 1-4, 7, 10, 11-15, 19,...).  You could do that once and print the hard copies yourself with a "copy quantity" parameter.
- You could select the print pages and produce a print version of the PDF that you distribute along with the full file so people can print their own copy.
- You could distribute, along with the PDF, instructions for how to print just the consolidated pages.
- You could create a macro or script that you distribute with the PDF that prints the selected pages.